# Delete by query not working even data exists on index

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm using delete by query in the PHP client for elasticsearch. I have elasticsearch index posts with some parent-child relations. So when I try to delete some records from child relation the query executes successfully and shows success but records are not deleted from the index, and most of the time query work properly. But this issue produced some time.

Field mapping type

```
"post_id" : {
     "type": "integer"
 }
```

**Query**

```
$query = [
            'index' => 'posts',
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'should' => [
                            [
                                "bool" => [
                                    "must" => [
                                        ['term' => ['type' => 'box_post']],
                                        ['term' => ['post_id' => (int) $post_id]]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                "bool" => [
                                    "must" => [
                                        ['term' => ['type' => 'post_box']],
                                        ['term' => ['post_id' => (int) $post_id]]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
 $this->client->deleteByQuery($query)
```

**Response**

```
Array
(
    [took] => 0
    [timed_out] => 
    [total] => 0
    [deleted] => 0
    [batches] => 0
    [version_conflicts] => 0
    [noops] => 0
    [retries] => Array
        (
            [bulk] => 0
            [search] => 0
        )

    [throttled_millis] => 0
    [requests_per_second] => -1
    [throttled_until_millis] => 0
    [failures] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Is there any way to make sure that if the record exists on the index then the query must delete the record instead of showing the success message with no record deleted?

Comment: If you print out the raw query and execute it against your cluster, what do you get?

Comment: @Val if I execute the raw query on kibana then it works fine but through code it some not delete the record

Comment: The exact same query? Very unlikely, unless you're hitting a different cluster. Also it's troubling to see `took: 0`

Comment: @Val is there any way to debug this issue as this query most of the time work fine on same index and cluster

Comment: Can you print out the query and add it to your question?

Comment: Also the query could be made simpler like this `'body' => [ 'query' => [ 'bool' => [  'filter' => [ ['terms' => ['type' => ['box_post', 'post_box']]],  ['term' => ['post_id' => (int) $post_id]] ]  ] ] ]` i.e. `terms` has OR semantics